# How to limit the range of a function in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have code like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw [->,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[ultra thick, domain=-5:5] plot (\x, {pow(\x,2)-5});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I draw this, the parabola is extremely exceeding the area of what I want. Is there a way to limit the range of the function f(x)=x^2-5 to suit the coordinate area, i.e. only show the points which y-coordinates are between -5 and 5?

Comment: Use `pgfplots`  instead ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to `TikZ` and `pgf`. I don't know in what circumstance had I better use `pgfplots`. Is `TikZ` not enough to use in some cases?

Comment: OK, I see the new answer by hbaderts.

Answer (score 11):

You could add a `\clip` before you do the plotting:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->,thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw [->,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[ultra thick, domain=-5:5] plot (\x, {pow(\x,2)-5});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think I should try to cope with `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 4):

Though the internal plot functions of Ti*k*Z work well for simple plots, I'd recommend using the PGFPlots package for more advanced plots. You can find the manual [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), and a nice gallery with examples of *everything* you can think of [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

With PGFPlots, your plot looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=6cm,
    height=6cm,
    title={A test plot},
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    axis lines=middle, 
    domain=-5:5,
    samples=100,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5
]

    \addplot[black, ultra thick] {pow(x,2)-5};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By default, PGFPlots draws a rectangle around the axis (see the examples page). To have single lines for the axis, use `axis lines=middle`.

With `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`, you tell PGFPlots to use version 1.13. I'd suggest you to set this value to the newest value you can. As long as you use a version >= 1.11, you can use normal Ti*k*Z commands, like `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);`, and the same coordinates as in the plot are used.

The result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for answering and giving the references! One more little question, how to make the downside of the parabola more smooth?

Comment: @Eric: Add something like `[samples=200]`or greater -not testet.

Comment: Exactly, as Hans-Peter E. Kristiansen says, with `samples=...` you can define the number of points. I added this to the answer. Note: with more points, the compilation time increases! I usually use 100, as this is often enough for normally-sized plots.

Comment: Instead of `samples=` you can simply add `smooth` to your `axis` options.

Comment: @Alenanno You should never smoothen closed form plots. They introduce junk.

Comment: @percusse What do you mean by "closed form plots"?

Comment: @Alenanno That has a formula

Comment: @percusse But I've seen the option being used before with formulas?

Comment: @Alenanno Well it shouldn't have been used. `smooth` basically modifies the data in plots and introduces stuff that it wasn't there in the first place.

Comment: How can I integrate TikZ original commands such like `\draw [->,thick] (-5,5) -- (5,4)` within the `pgfplot` environment?

Comment: @Eric Try using `(axis cs:<coordinates>)`, is that what you mean?

Comment: When I use something like `\draw [->,thick] (-5,5) -- (5,4)`, the result gets wrong due to the use of different coordinates.

Comment: @Eric: see the edited answer. If you set the version to at least 1.11, then the coordinates will be correct.

Comment: with the command `axis lines=middle`, the original point of the coordinate system in the presentation moves to the middle of the page, but its actual coordinate is not (0,0) as expected, it's something like (5,5). How to make them consistent? ie. letting the original point truly be an original point (0,0).

Comment: @Alenanno oh yes, I just changed to use `(axis cs:<coordinates>)` and move the `\draw` into `axis` environment , and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If your LaTeX installation is able to call Gnuplot as an external program you could replace

```
\draw[ultra thick, domain=-5:5] plot (\x, {pow(\x,2)-5});
```

by

```
\draw[ultra thick] plot[domain=-5:5, yrange=-5:5] function{x*x-5};
```

See the section "Plotting a Function Using Gnuplot" in the [TikZ/PGF](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) manual.