# How can I get the correct result with this picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw like this picture
[image]

I tried.

***First way*** (I got the correct result)

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={ 
xmin=-1;xmax=10;ymin=-3;ymax=2;}] 
\draw[gray!30] (xmin,ymin) grid (xmax,ymax); % grid 
\draw[->, thick] (xmin,0)--(xmax,0) node [below left]{$x$}; 
\draw[->,thick] (0,ymin)--(0,ymax) node [below left]{$y$}; 
\node[below right] at (0, 0) {$O$}; 
\foreach \p/\g in {1/-90,2/-45,3/-90,4/90,5/-90,6/-45,7/-90,8/-90,9/-90 }\draw(\p,0)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\foreach \p/\g in {-2/180,1/180}\draw(0,\p)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\draw[very thick] (2,0)
arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (6,0)
arc [start angle=0, end angle=-180, radius=2];
\draw[thick] (6,0) -- (9,1);
\foreach \Y in {(2,0),(4,-2),(6,0),(9,1)} \fill \Y circle(2pt); 
\draw[dashed] (9,0) |- (0,1);
\draw[dashed] (4,0) |- (0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

***Second way*** (I didn't get the correct result)

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={ 
xmin=-1;xmax=10;ymin=-3;ymax=2;
f(\x)=sqrt(2*\x- \x*\x);
g(\x)=-sqrt(-12 + 8*\x - \x*\x);
}] 
%\draw[gray!30] (xmin,ymin) grid (xmax,ymax); % grid 
\draw[->, thick] (xmin,0)--(xmax,0) node [below left]{$x$}; 
\draw[->,thick] (0,ymin)--(0,ymax) node [below left]{$y$}; 
\node[below right] at (0, 0) {$O$}; 
\foreach \p/\g in {1/-90,2/-45,3/-90,4/90,5/-90,6/-45,7/-90,8/-90,9/-90 }\draw(\p,0)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\foreach \p/\g in {-2/180,1/180}\draw(0,\p)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\draw[thick] (6,0) -- (9,1);
%\foreach \Y in {(2,0),(4,-2),(6,0),(9,1)} \fill \Y circle(2pt); 
\draw[dashed] (9,0) |- (0,1);
\draw[dashed] (4,0) |- (0,-2);
\draw[very thick,blue,smooth,samples=250,domain=0:2] plot(\x,{f(\x)});
\draw[very thick,blue,smooth,samples=250,domain=2:6] plot(\x,{g(\x)});  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

How can I get the correct result with second way?
[image]

Comment: Why at all do you want to get the result with the second way?

Comment: @JouleV We can easy to see the equations of two curves. Therefore, I tried with the second way.

Comment: Do you think the readers will be able to view the equations of the curves? If they don't, it is not necessary, because of course the owner of the file clearly has to know the equations of these curves. And, obviously, the readers have no means to know the equation except by reading the source themselves. Also, I don't think there will be any person who reads the source without sufficient information. As for the curve, this can be said to be a drawback of Ti*k*Z `plot` for functions which are defined on only a limited domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [awesome answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453416/152550) you need to put `plot function` instead of only add `plot`.

I have tried and I could not find a way to use `plot function` within `f(\x)` or `g(\x)`, so I deleted them and replaced by their definitions that were in `declare function` to get your first way (btw I do not know why you forget to add blue color, the black points and grid background):

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={ 
xmin=-1;xmax=10;ymin=-3;ymax=2;
%f(\x)=sqrt(2*\x- \x*\x); % deleted
%g(\x)=-sqrt(-12 + 8*\x - \x*\x); % deleted
}] 
%\draw[gray!30] (xmin,ymin) grid (xmax,ymax); % grid 
\draw[->, thick] (xmin,0)--(xmax,0) node [below left]{$x$}; 
\draw[->,thick] (0,ymin)--(0,ymax) node [below left]{$y$}; 
\node[below right] at (0, 0) {$O$}; 
\foreach \p/\g in {1/-90,2/-45,3/-90,4/90,5/-90,6/-45,7/-90,8/-90,9/-90 }\draw(\p,0)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\foreach \p/\g in {-2/180,1/180}\draw(0,\p)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\draw[thick] (6,0) -- (9,1);
%\foreach \Y in {(2,0),(4,-2),(6,0),(9,1)} \fill \Y circle(2pt); 
\draw[dashed] (9,0) |- (0,1);
\draw[dashed] (4,0) |- (0,-2);
\draw[very thick,blue,smooth,samples=250,domain=0:2] plot function{sqrt(2*x- x*x)};
\draw[very thick,blue,smooth,samples=250,domain=2:6] plot function{-sqrt(-12 + 8*x - x*x)};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I don't understand why, I don't get the curves.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why this happens (seems that this has to do with the conversion between cm and pt and some numerical errors) and manoooh's answer is the cleaner way to go. This is just in case you do not have gnuplot installed. Then you can just "continue" the functions in such a way that they remain well-defined and plot over a slightly longer interval.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={ 
xmin=-1;xmax=10;ymin=-3;ymax=2;
f(\x)=ifthenelse(2*\x- \x*\x>0,sqrt(abs(2*\x- \x*\x)),0);
g(\x)=-ifthenelse(-12 + 8*\x - \x*\x>0,sqrt(abs(-12 + 8*\x - \x*\x)),0);
}] 
%\draw[gray!30] (xmin,ymin) grid (xmax,ymax); % grid 
\draw[->, thick] (xmin,0)--(xmax,0) node [below left]{$x$}; 
\draw[->,thick] (0,ymin)--(0,ymax) node [below left]{$y$}; 
\node[below right] at (0, 0) {$O$}; 
\foreach \p/\g in {1/-90,2/-45,3/-90,4/90,5/-90,6/-45,7/-90,8/-90,9/-90 }\draw(\p,0)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\foreach \p/\g in {-2/180,1/180}\draw(0,\p)node[shift={(\g:.3)},scale=1]{$\p$}--+(0,.05)--+(0,-.05); 
\draw[thick] (6,0) -- (9,1);
%\foreach \Y in {(2,0),(4,-2),(6,0),(9,1)} \fill \Y circle(2pt); 
\draw[dashed] (9,0) |- (0,1);
\draw[dashed] (4,0) |- (0,-2);
\draw[very thick,blue] plot[smooth,samples=250,domain=0:2.003](\x,{f(\x)});
\draw[very thick,blue] plot[smooth,samples=250,domain=2:6.003](\x,{g(\x)});  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]